# Failed to detect local database from client PC in my C# Windows application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, local-database

I have a simple Winforms app (C#) in development it works perfectly on my laptop, and I am just trying to test to see if I can publish it for others to use.

It uses a local Microsoft SQL Server database file (`SqlClient`). I tried publishing what I have (so far) to my friend's PC. When he opened the app, this error appeared and he couldn't access to local database.

This is the `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="sell.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"
             connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

This is the error:

[image]

I use the local database like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sell.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
```

Any solutions to fix the problem?

Comment: SQL Server is *not* a file-based database. LocalDB is a special feature of SQL Server Express, meant mainly only for development. Have you installed SQL Server Express on the target machine?

Comment: Yes to what @PanagiotisKanavos said. Also you probably want to look into Sqlite instead.

Comment: yes i install SQL server Express

Comment: To get your SQL Server instance name, open Powershell and type: `Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Microsoft\SqlServer  -Query "Select Name from __Namespace where Name like 'ComputerManagement%'" | ForEach-Object { $sqlMgmtVer = $_.Name; Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Microsoft\SqlServer\$sqlMgmtVer -Class FileStreamSettings |Select-Object InstanceName }`

Comment: You need to install SQL Server Express **LocalDB** (not the "full" Express edition)

Comment: Visual studio > view > Server Explorer then Connect to your server and database, then right click to the database go to properties copy the connection string and replace the part 'Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB'. for example: Data Source=YogaS1;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string specifies this: `Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;`. If you have installed SQL Server Express, rather than just LocalDB, then that's not going to work. You need to change the data source to refer to the SQL Server Express instance on the local machine, e.g. `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;`.

Comment: if i change it to Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; its not working on my pc and my friend pc to

Comment: @Flanc, where did I give any indication that you should change the connection string on your own machine? I didn't. It's perfectly reasonable and common for the connection string to be different on the developer's machine and that of an end user. That's why the connection string is stored in the config file and not hard-coded in the app.

Comment: Im beginner in this how i can fixed step by step i'm totally desperate

Comment: @Flanc, I've already told you what to do. Just do it. It's editing a bit of text. We shouldn't need to explain that step by step. We should be able to assume a minimum level of proficiency with the basics.

Comment: @Flanc, you are deploying the config file with the executable, right? If not, that's your mistake. That's the file that needs to be edited ON THE END USER'S MACHINE.

Comment: Yes i deployed the app.exe.config